# Installing R on Apache Zeppelin

Tags: r, apache, apache-zeppelin

I'm trying to install Apache Zeppelin on my old computer that runs Ubuntu. So far, I'm able to install Zeppelin very easily by cloning the latest 0.6.0 snapshot release using

```
git clone https://github.com/apache/incubator-zeppelin.git
cd incubator-zeppelin
mvn clean package -DskipTests
```

but I want to have R on Zeppelin. Supposedly, the 0.6.0 snapshot has two R interpreters, but when I run the R tutorial (the pre-made note that uses %r), [I get this list of errors.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFPaL.png)

I followed several guides to try and install R as an interpreter, but each one resulted in some kind of error. I tried this instructional: 
http://www.r-bloggers.com/interactive-data-science-with-r-in-apache-zeppelin-notebook/, and got a build failure on "R Interpreter". The error message was

```
"dependency 'evaluate' is not available for package 'rzeppelin' 
* removing '/home/rebecca/Zeppelin-With-R/R/lib/rzeppelin'"
```

and then a bit lower down

```
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default) on project zeppelin-zrinterpreter: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 1
```

I also tried this Stack Overflow guide: [Anyone tried to add R interpreter onto Apache Zeppelin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33421426/anyone-tried-to-add-r-interpreter-onto-apache-zeppelin), and while I was able to run incubator-zeppelin, I received an error when I used either the %spark.r or %r interpreter tags, saying both "interpreter not found" and "prefix not found". Spark doesn't work either after following the first solution, getting the same error mentioned in the second solution (the jar file not being there), and then trying the second solution.

Does anyone have a guide for installing R onto the newest version of Zeppelin? I'm very flexible in the way I can install it. I can run other operating systems onto my computer, and I also have Virtual Box installed on my other computer, which is a mac.

Comment: I also saw this guide online: https://gist.github.com/nsabharwal/9163e0adfc66af080145, but was unsure of how it worked.

Answer (score 0):

> There is currently a bug in the latest HEAD of zeppelin that was recently introduced and prevents the R interpreter from launching cleanly

Did anyone created a Zeppelin Jira Issue for that?

For me it is working on Zeppelin [branch-0.6](https://github.com/apache/zeppelin/tree/branch-0.6)

1. build Zeppelin with r profile: *-DskipTests -Pr*
   this will...

   1. create a **directory 'R'** in git repo root
   2. copy the **'zeppelin-rinterpreter*.jar'** into git_repo_root/interpreter/spark
2. build Zeppelin with build distro profile: e.g. *-DskipTests -Pbuild-distr -Pspark-1.6 -Phadoop-2.6*
3. use zeppelin-distribution/target/zeppelin*.tar.gz for installation
4. **ensure both 1.1 and 1.2 are present in your zeppelin installation**

Answer (score -1):

The error you're getting is that you need to have the R package `evaluate` installed.  You can install this simply by launching R and typing `install.packages('evaluate')`.

That said, your excerpt mentions the directory `Zeppelin-with-R`.  That's my repo, which is the R interpreter in the form when it was accepted into Zeppelin.  That is version 0.5.6, not 0.6.0.  There is currently a bug in the latest HEAD of zeppelin that was recently introduced and prevents the R interpreter from launching cleanly.  Your best bet for now is to use the one from my repo and install clean, without trying to pull-in from Zeppelin HEAD.